# WPF: Add UiElements to grid/Itemscontrol performance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphic

We have a device that takes measurements (up to 1000 per second). Now I wanted to create a view that draws that measurements to a grid or something. My problem is how to handle that amount of data in that short period of time, I've created a little testapp that draws a point every 10ms to a grid. Up to 2000 points the app freezes. When I draw 5000 or more points instantly to a grid, it's no problem and works fine. Is WPF to slow, have I to use a special graphics library?

```
private void _Content_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var grid = new Grid()
                   {
                       Width = 5000,
                       Height = 5000
                   };
        var viewBox = new Viewbox
                      {
                          Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
                          Child = grid
                      };
        _Content.Content = viewBox;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            var child = new Ellipse()
                        {
                            Width = 200,
                            Height = 200,
                            Fill = Brushes.Blue
                        };
            ((FrameworkElement) child).Margin = new Thickness(random.Next(4800), random.Next(4800), random.Next(4800), random.Next(4800));
            grid.Children.Add(child);
        }
    }
```

Thats the code of the little testapp, I also tried it with a data binding and an observable collection but it's not a huge difference.

Comment: Putting some code will give us some idea about your code optimization.

Comment: Ideally you don't want to be taking measurements on the UI thread, consider implementing another thread for data acquisition.

Comment: What do you mean by 5000 points works fine instantly, but 2000 points and the app freezes?

Comment: @RohitPrakash The measurements are taken on an another thread, just the UI-things are done on the UI-Thread.

Comment: @user3690202 the 5000 points are drawed with a for loop, without a break. The 2000 points are drawed with a thread.sleep(10) between each point.

Comment: Using Margin to lay out items isn't the most logical way to do this. Grid is one of the most complex (i.e. slow) layout controls in WPF. You should use a Canvas which is the quickest, and then just use X, Y coordinates to position your points. I suspect it will still be too slow, but at least you will be doing things the right way.

Comment: @HansDabi That Thread.Sleep is inside the Dispatcher invocation?

Comment: @OlaruMircea No it's outside.

Comment: I think we need the code for the case which freezes. Also, try wrapping the inside of the dispatcher invocation with some Stopwatch instrumentation calls and log the time it takes to execute. Is your dispatcher call Invoke() or BeginInvoke(). It could be that you are issuing dispatcher calls faster than they are running, and in the end the Dispatcher hangs.

Comment: As a test, change from BeginInvoke() to Invoke() which will be synchronous. then, if it doesn't hang anymore, you know that you are overloading the dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is happening is that you are doing BeginInvoke() every 10ms, but the dispatcher is not able to execute the dispatched code fast enough. So more and more dispatched calls are building up, until the application no longer functions.

I would be very surprised if you are able to dispatch and have executed the code in 10ms in WPF.

Comment: Thats right, but when I stop the measurement stream on 1500-2000 items the application runs very laggy and no items are generated at this point. Normally in this case an application would run laggy while the items are incoming and shortly after until the queue is finished. But not in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. By the time you have dispatched 2000 asynchronous invokes, your application will be very laggy probably for a long time afterwards. It would seem pretty simple to work out whether the queue is finished or not, right? Have you checked whether the queue is finished, or are you just assuming that it hasnt?

Comment: The queue is finished, I checked that, but the application is still laggy and has about 13% cpu usage although nothing is calculating or generating.

Comment: And you are saying that 5000 items added all at once is not laggy? So you are saying that the only difference between the "5000-works-great" case and the "2000-doesnt-work" case is the way they are added, i.e. by a BeginInvoke(). But that the dispatcher completes all the queued 2000 dispatches (which I find hard to believe, btw), so somehow by adding them in individual dispatches is has changed something internally (again, hard to believe). Is that your thinking?

Comment: Yes thats pretty it :) the only difference is that the 5000 items are created on the ui-thread without a dipatcher and the 2000 with a dispatcher on a seperate thread with a thread.sleep. I find it hard to believe too, therefor I posted this question :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want as an answer. It's pretty obvious that your current design is not going to work. It's pretty obvious why - dispatching code faster than it can be executed is not going to work. As to your conclusions, my personal suspicion is that you are mistaken and the dispatcher is still overloaded after it's mistreatment. I doubt you are going to get much more than this, unless you post some actual code.

Comment: Typically in this situation I separate the data update code from the code to refresh the UI. I.e. on a thread you collect your data every 10ms, and add it to your data model, and then in your UI you maybe have a timer which refreshes 2 times per second, and that updates your UI. This way you don't have a link between a high frequency data input thread and a refresh of the UI.